# Соединение было сброшено. при загрузке файла на сервер

Tags: java, servlet

пытаюсь отправлять файлы к себе на сервер,некоторые файлы отправляет нормально, а при попытке других в браузере выскакивает ошибка "Соединение было сброшено" подскажите, почему возникает эта ошибка?
это ошибка браузера или моя?

```
@WebServlet("/qwe")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 10)
public class WebApp extends HttpServlet {
    private String q;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        q = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "data";
        File file = new File(q);
        file.mkdir();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Part part = req.getPart("file");
        InputStream inputStreamReader = part.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(q + File.separator + "qwe.rar");
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 20];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStreamReader.read(buff)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("bytesRead = " + bytesRead);
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStreamReader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: вас дебажить не учили? брейкпоинты ставить?

Comment: @Санаев спасибо, я разобрался

Comment: в настройках tomcat стоит ограничение размера на прием  файлов